# Merge values from multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following object:

```
"themes": [
    {
      "name": "Anchor",
      "categories": "Creative, Portfolio",
    },
    {
      "name": "Agensy",
      "categories": "Creative, Portfolio",
    },
    {
      "name": "Serenity Pro",
      "categories": "One-Page, Multipurpose, Business, Landing Page",
    },
    {
      "name": "Integral Pro",
      "categories": "One-Page, Multipurpose, Business, Landing Page",
    }
  ]
```

I want to iterate through each array and collect the values of the **categories** key

Then remove duplicates and spit out an array of unique category names.

I have the following code:

```
$json = $this->curl_get_marketplace_contents();
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$categories = array();
foreach ($array['themes'] as $theme) {
    $array = explode(",", $theme['categories']);
    $array = array_map('trim', $array);
    $array = array_values($array);
    $array = array_unique($array);
    $categories = array_push($array, $categories);
    
};
return $categories;
```

But it's not working. It returns empty.

I feel like I'm close but I'm making a noob mistake. If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You're using the same variable `$array` for the original JSON array and the temporary array inside the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing onto `$categories`, not `$array`?

Comment: None of your categories have any duplicates. And there's no need to use `array_values`, since `$array` isn't an associative array after `explode()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge()` to combine arrays, not `array_push()`.

Remove the duplicates at the end after merging everything.

```
$json = $this->curl_get_marketplace_contents();
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$categories = array();
foreach ($data['themes'] as $theme) {
    $array = explode(",", $theme['categories']);
    $array = array_map('trim', $array);
    $categories = array_merge($array, $categories);
    
};
return array_unique($categories);
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. How do I then order then alphabetically? Use asort() ?

Comment: Sort the array with `sort()`. `asort()` is for associative arrays.